# Make a tabbed div container dynamic to its content

Tags: html, css

I tried to implement [this](http://tinyurl.com/ja8fxf2) example on a website. Now, if you add content or simply make the lorem ipsum text a bit longer, the content will soon be bigger than its containing container. How do I change the size of the container dynamically in regard to its content? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's problematic because of the `position: absolute`which all the containers have (otherwise they wouldn't be on top of each other, but underneath each other). And an absolutely positioned container needs a defined "height" or at least "min-heigth". You might find a good value for `#content {min-width: ... }` by trial and error.

Comment: there's a mistake in my previous comment: I meant to suggest to find a value for `#content: min-height: ... }` , not for "min-width"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess we will have to do with finding a make-do solution then. It's a bit complicated, because we have many strict (and stupid) limitations from very high up. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overflow property in your css.
Try this:

```
.content{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That makes the container scrollable. Although that's an "okay" solution, I'd like the container to gain height with more content. How would you do that?